# WiX and InstallCommand

Tags: xml, wix, appdata

I'm using WIX [Link](http://wixtoolset.org), and I'm instaling *exe file, lets say program.exe by:

```
      <ExePackage Id="Dependency1" Name="Program" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
              InstallCommand="/S CONF_FILE=&quot;%appdata%/program/programConfig.xml&quot;; ..."
              SourceFile="program.exe"/>
```

And it's dont load that files, the path is ok, and when I'm starting program.exe by cmd:

```
program.exe  CONF_FILE="%appdata%/program/programConfig.xml"
```

it works fine, is there any problem refering to appdata in WIX?

Comment: Seems like those forward slashes should be blackslashes. `cmd` may be fixing those for you automatically.

Comment: Changing forward slashes to backslashes didnt help

Comment: What is showing up in the logs as the command being run? My msi logs show up in `%APPDATA%\Local\Temp\*.msi.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burn doesn't expand environment variables.  You need to use the built-in Burn variable [`AppDataFolder`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html)

```
InstallCommand='/S CONF_FILE="[AppDataFolder]program\programConfig.xml" ...'
```